# chartnew.js cannot show chart after durandal project published

Tags: chart.js

i use chart.js in my durandal project to draw chart, then i found some limits of the library, and i found another one named chartnew.js, which is very like chart.js, but chartnew.js is more powerful. everything goes fine, the charts look nice.

but when i published the project,i meet a very mysterious issue: 
the charts are not appear in the server, but when i change the debug='true' in webconfig, it works, all the charts appear on the screen.

do you guys have any ideas on this situation?

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is the slight server side delay introduced by your `debug=true` delays the chart initialization just enough so that the canvas element has non-zero size when `new Chart...` is called.

One easy way to confirm if this is the case is to ensure that your canvas HTML is always visible (i.e. take off any code that dynamically hides it / shows it...) and see if the issue occurs.

You need to ensure that the canvas element is visible when the Chart data is loaded i.e. `new Chart...` is called.

I think `resizeGraph` and / or `chartJsResize` (for ChartNew.js) could also be used to force a redraw (say, with a setTimeout with enough delay to ensure that the canvas element has been rendered)

Comment: thanks for your explaining, but i tested both static data and dynamic data, the results are same, i think is not the delays.

Comment: and i find a clue from [chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) :     Alternatively, if you're using an AMD loader for JavaScript modules, that is also supported in the Chart.js core. Please note: the library will still occupy a global variable of Chart, even if it detects define and define.amd. If this is a problem, you can call noConflict to restore the global Chart variable to it's previous owner...

Comment: more than the data being static, a static canvas element (something that is always visible / same size) would probably help.

Comment: i set  borders to the canvases, and all the borders appear except the charts

Comment: The borders would appear, because they are not dependent on the Chart.js code. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Actually,chart.js works, but when I switch to chartnew.js, charts are disappear. And I get no error, all the log I put In the ChartNew.js are shown in console. From firebug, The only difference is window.chart is red(scope like $,jQuery) when I use chart.js but green when I use ChartNew.js.  in debug mode, window.chart is same as in publishing mode, is green too, but only works in debug mode

Comment: What limitations are you trying to work around in Chart.js with ChartNew.js?

Comment: New chart type:bar with line, title and the easy use of legend, I have compared two codes, have not find the reason why window.chart is not the same scope